# What is the best algo for this array minimization problem?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, pseudocode, minimization

I have an array say 'A' of size n having some numbers {a1, a2, …, an} not necessarily distinct.
I have to create another array B = {b1, b2, …, bn} which are distinct such that the value of
sum|ai - bi| over all i's{i =1 to i =n} is minimized.

Basically I want to minimize sum of |ai - bi| over all i

What is the best algo for this?

I tried a greedy approach:

pseudocode:

```
for i = 0 to n-1{
 if(a[i] not in b){
  b[i] = a[i];}
 else{
  cnt = 1
  assigned = false
 do{
  if(a[i]-cnt not in b){
   b[i] = a[i]-cnt;
   assigned = true}
  elif(a[i]+cnt not in b){
   b[i] = a[i]+cnt;
   assigned = true}
  else
   cnt++
 }while(assigned==false)
}//else
}//for loop
```

NOte:
'n' is an input variable.
the goal is to minimize sum of |ai - bi| over all i

Comment: Welcome to SO. Firstly, please tag a language. Secondly, please show us what you've tried.

Comment: No, don't tag a language. Tag [language-agnostic] if you must.

Comment: @Mitya i added the tag, and the best soln i could think of

Comment: What is the expected output? The `b[i]` or the minimum sum? And what is the maximum size `n` of the problem?

Comment: @Damien 'n' is an input variable., a is an array of length 'n' which is also an input
the goal is to create an array b(of len n)  so that it minimizes sum of |ai - bi| over all i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a **O(NlogN)** solution. Its based on sorting the input-sequence and greedily expanding the available numbers around it.

#### Code implementation in Python:

```
def get_closest_distinct_tuple(X: list):
    X = sorted(X, reverse=True)
    hmap = {}
    used_set = set()

    Y = []

    for x in X:
        if x not in used_set:
            Y.append(x)
            hmap[x] = 1
            used_set.add(x)
        else:
            Y.append(x + hmap[x])
            used_set.add(x + hmap[x])
            hmap[x] = 1 - hmap[x] if hmap[x] < 0 else -hmap[x]

    dist = sum([abs(X[i]-Y[i]) for i in range(len(X))])
    return dist, Y


print(get_closest_distinct_tuple([20, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]))
```

Output:

```
Dist: 9
Y = [20, 1, 2, 0, 3, -1, 4]
```

I couldnt really find a way to prove that this is the most optimal solution out there.